# Fallo Haml syntax error, unexpected { arg, expecting ']'

Tags: haml

Cual sera el error esto es lo que me aparece al intentarlo compilar 
--->HAML: Compiling failed:

Syntax error on line 131: /Users/ernevizcaino/Documents/Proyecto Curso Frontend/index.haml:56: syntax error, unexpected { arg, expecting ']'
...mage:"pollo", pricing:"12.00"}{name: "Spaguetti", image:"spa...
...                               ^
  Use --trace for backtrace.

```
 !!!5
%html{class:"no-js", lang:"es"}
  %head
    %meta{charset:"utf-8"}
    %title La mejor comida.
    %meta{name:"description", content:"Come rico en el mejor restaurante de la ciudad, servicio de primera."}
    %link{rel:"stylesheet", href:"css/normalize.css"}
    %link{rel:"stylesheet", href:"css/bootstrap.css"}
    %link{rel:"stylesheet", href:"css/flexboxgrid.css"}
    %link{rel:"stylesheet", href:"css/style.css"}
    %link{rel:"stylesheet", href:"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico"}
    %meta{name:"viewport", content:"width=device-width, initial-scale=1"}
    %script{src:"js/vendor/modernizr.js"}

  %body
    ="<!--[if lt IE 9]>"
    %p{class:"browserupgrade"}
    Estas usando un navegador
    %strong desactualizado.
    Por favor
    %a{href:"browsehappy.com"}
    actualiza tu navegador
    para una mejor experiencia
    ="<![endif]-->"
    .video-container
      %video{autoplay:true, loop:true, width:"1280", height:"720", poster:"/videos/Snapshots/Night-BBQ.jpg"}
        %source{src:"/videos/MP4/Night-BBQ.mp4",typ:"video/mp4"}
        %source{src:"/videos/WEBM/Night-BBQ.webm",typ:"video/webm"}

    .row.full-height.middle-xs.center-xs.relative.up#home
      .col-xs-12
        .box.whitetext
          %img{src:"/imgs/logoo.png", width:250}
          %h1.cursive.big-text.no-margin Restaurante Nene's
          %p#is-open 
            %i.glyphicon.glyphicon-time
            Abierto ahora
      %nav.fixed.top.right.navigation.whitetext#navigation
        -menu = ["Inicio", "Menu", "Galeria", "Contacto", "Como llegar"]
        %ul.list-inline.medium
          -menu.each do |item|
            %li
              %a{}= item
      .absolute.medium1.black.large-padding.whitetext.full-widht#description
        .row.middle-xs.center-xs
          .col-xs-7.col-sm-6.whitetext.medium.bold
            Atencion de primera y comida preparada por artistas
          .col-xs.hidden#sticky-navigation
            .box.bold
              %nav.text-right.navigation
                %ul.list-inline
                  -menu.each do |item|
                    %li
                      %a{}= item
    .text-center#menu
      - menu_photos = [{name: "Hamburguesa", image:"hamburguesa", pricing:"10.00"},{name: "Hot Dogs", image:"hot-dogs", pricing:"5.00"},{name: "Pizza", image:"pizza", pricing:"18.00"},{name: "Pollo", image:"pollo", pricing:"12.00"}{name: "Spaguetti", image:"spaguetti", pricing:"7.00"}{name: "Tacos", image:"tacos", pricing:"2.00"}{name: "Tacos-Carne", image:"tacosx2", pricing:"3.00"}{name: "Tamales", image:"tamales", pricing:"3.00"}]
    .row
      - menu_photos.each do |photo| 
        .col-md-4.col-lg-3.col-sm-6.col-xs-12.food{style:"background-image:url(/imgs/food/#{photo[:image]}.jpg)"}




    %script{src:"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js",integrity:"sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=",crossorigin:"anonymous"}
    %script
      window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='js/vendor/jquery-1.12.0.js'><\/ script>")
    %script{src:"/js/main.js"}
```

Comment: Te falta una coma despues de `{name: "Pollo", image:"pollo", pricing:"12.00"}`

Comment: Muchas gracias alanfcm me funciono